# efficient way of calculating Monte Carlo results for different impact assessment methods in Brightway

Tags: brightway

I am trying to do a comparative monte carlo calculation with brightway2 using different impact assessment methods. I thought about using the `switch_method` method to be more efficient, since the technosphere matrix is the same for a given iteration. However, I am getting an assertion error. A code to reproduce it could be something like this

```py
    import brighway as bw
    bw.projects.set_current('ei35') # project with ecoinvent 3.5
    db = bw.Database("ei_35cutoff")

    # select two different transport activities to compare
    activity_name = 'transport, freight, lorry >32 metric ton, EURO4'    
    for activity in bw.Database("ei_35cutoff"):
        if activity['name'] == activity_name:
            truckE4 = bw.Database("ei_35cutoff").get(activity['code'])
            print(truckE4['name'])
            break

    activity_name = 'transport, freight, lorry >32 metric ton, EURO6'    
    for activity in bw.Database("ei_35cutoff"):
        if activity['name'] == activity_name:
            truckE6 = bw.Database("ei_35cutoff").get(activity['code'])
            print(truckE6['name'])
            break

    demands = [{truckE4: 1}, {truckE6: 1}]

    # impact assessment method:
    recipe_midpoint=[method for method in bw.methods.keys() 
    if method[0]=="ReCiPe Midpoint (H)"]

    mc_mm = bw.MonteCarloLCA(demands[0], recipe_midpoint[0])
    next(mc_mm)
```

If I try switch method I get the assertion error.

```py
    mc_mm.switch_method(recipe_midpoint[1])
    assert mc_mm.method==recipe_midpoint[1]
    mc_mm.redo_lcia()
    next(mc_mm)
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually store characterization factor matrices in a temporary dict and multiply these cfs with the LCI resulting from MonteCarloLCA directly.

```
import brightway2 as bw
import numpy as np

# Generate objects for analysis

bw.projects.set_current("my_mcs")
my_db = bw.Database('db')
my_act = my_db.random()
my_demand = {my_act:1}
my_methods = [bw.methods.random() for _ in range(2)]
```

I wrote this simple function to get characterization factor matrices for the product system I will generate in the MonteCarloLCA. It uses a temporara "sacrificial LCA" object that will have the same A and B matrices as the MonteCarloLCA. 
This may seem like a waste of time, but it is only done once, and will make MonteCarlo quicker and simpler.

```
def get_C_matrices(demand, list_of_methods):
    """ Return a dict with {method tuple:cf_matrix} for a list of methods
    Uses a "sacrificial LCA" with exactly the same demand as will be used
    in the MonteCarloLCA
    """
    C_matrices = {}
    sacrificial_LCA = bw.LCA(demand)
    sacrificial_LCA.lci()
    for method in list_of_methods:
        sacrificial_LCA.switch_method(method)
        C_matrices[method] = sacrificial_LCA.characterization_matrix
    return C_matrices
```

Then:

```
# Create array that will store mc results.
# Shape is (number of methods, number of iteration)

my_iterations = 10
mc_scores = np.empty(shape=[len(my_methods), my_iterations])

# Instantiate MonteCarloLCA object
my_mc = bw.MonteCarloLCA(my_demand)

# Get characterization factor matrices
my_C_matrices = get_C_matrices(my_demand, my_methods)

# Generate results
for iteration in range(my_iterations):
    lci = next(my_mc)
    for i, m in enumerate(my_methods):
        mc_scores[i, iteration] = (my_C_matrices[m]*my_mc.inventory).sum()
```

All your results are in mc_scores. Each row corresponds to a method, each column to an MC iteration.

Comment: This is the right answer - the slow part is loading processed data and building matrices, which is what the `switch_method` function has to do each time. Build the `C` matrices once, and you will get maximum speed.

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but try this:

```
iterations = 10 
simulations = []

for _ in range(iterations):
    mc_mm = MonteCarloLCA(demands[0], recipe_midpoint[0])
    next(mc_mm)

    mcresults = []
    for i in demands:    
        print(i)
        for m in recipe_midpoint[0:3]:
            mc_mm.switch_method(m)
            print(mc_mm.method)    
            mc_mm.redo_lcia(i)
            print(mc_mm.score)
            mcresults.append(mc_mm.score)
    simulations.append(mcresults)

CC_truckE4 = [i[1] for i in simulations] # Climate Change, truck E4 
CC_truckE6 = [i[1+3] for i in simulations] # Climate Change, truck E6

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
plt.plot(CC_truckE4 , CC_truckE6, 'o')
```

If you then make a test and do twice the simulation for the same demand vector, by setting `demands = [{truckE4: 1}, {truckE4: 1}]` and plot the result you should get a straight line. This means that you are doing dependent sampling and re-using the same tech matrix for each demand vector and for each LCIA. I am not 100% sure of this but I hope it answers your question.