# MultiMonteCarlo with multiple impact categories

Tags: python-3.x, brightway

I need to perform a Montecarlo analysis with different demand vectors and multiple LCIA methods. I am using the MultiMonteCarlo class in Brightway2, but it only allows a single LCIA method to be used. In order to compute results for different impact categories, I tried to refer to some useful methods implemented in the MonteCarloLCA class, such as `.switch_method()` and `.characterization_matrix()`, but these are not implemented in MultiMonteCarlo. Looking at the python code of this class, it is not easy to understand how I may define a new function able to perform my analysis.
How can I store the inventory results at each iteration and compute the related impacts for different categories?

Comment: Welcome to SO, @Davide.
This question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57679234/efficient-way-of-calculating-monte-carlo-results-for-different-impact-assessment/57693830#57693830)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The function you created works for multiple iterations of a Montecarlo with different impact methods. Since I also wanted to add another dimension (i.e. the demand), I developed my code starting from your indications and what I found in https://github.com/PoutineAndRosti/Brightway-Seminar-2017